# Why do I need to put the reference to a sheet named R in quotes?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My workbook contains three sheets. Two of them are filled with lookup data, one for "left" named `L` and one for "right" named `R`.

When referencing cells from those two worksheets on the third worksheet, I can write `=L!$A$2`, but I need to write `='R'!$A$2` (note the quotes around the sheet name).

When I write `='L'!$A$2`, Excel removes the quotes, so apparently they aren't needed for the `L` sheet. But when I write `=R!$A$2`, I get an error message telling me there's a problem with that formula, where the message and its fix assume I didn't want to put a formula in the first place. Only the quoted version works.

However, "R" does not seem to be any native Excel function. In fact, `=L` is a valid input (resolves to a `#NAME?` error, but I can enter it), where `=R` throws the error for an invalid formula and won't let me save that input at all.

This happens in the current Office 365 version as well as MS Excel 2007.

What's going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the same behavior if you name a sheet `C`.  Excel has the option to use `R1C1` addressing modes, so the requirement to put those particular characters in quotes is to avoid the confusion that would occur should you change mode.

You'll also see this behavior if you, for example,  try to name a sheet with a A1 cell range reference:  A123!A1 will convert to 'A123'!A1

Comment: That makes sense! I found that `S` and `Z` show the same behaviour, because in my Excel (German), `R1C3` would be `Z1S3` (I found Z earlier but didn't want to try the whole alphabet). So C, R, S and Z are reserved for row/col notation in my system's language and English as base language.